# Prevent target="_top" from taking over UI in Mozilla Chromeless

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner, chromeless

I know a fix for this is coming soon; I'm just hoping to get a head start.

Chromeless is basically Firefox without it's UI. You can build your own UI using HTML, CSS, and javascript. Tabs/windows are loaded in iframes. The main frame (the browser UI) has special priviledges that allow it to control the iframes. The iframes think they are the "top" document (`top === self`).

There have been a couple issues with the way they have implemented these sandboxed iframes. One of which is that links with `target="_top"` are loaded in the browser UI; not in the iframe. They do NOT respect the iframe sandbox.

Obviously this causes some problems if anyone wants to implement a real browser in chromeless.

If you are familiar with Chromeless, Gecko/XulRunner, firefox, and/or building firefox extensions and have an idea as to where and what I should modify to further lock down the iframe sandbox by forcing `_top` to always equal the iframe `self` please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do this with HTML frames, you have to use `<xul:browser type="content-primary"/>` or equivalent.

Comment: What I'm doing until this is fixed in chromeless is watching for attached nodes and changed attributes on links and forcing them to target=_self. Its not nearly a complete solutions and will fail on nested iframes; but it works for the most part (for now)